# how to Run tests based on category in teamcity using mstest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, selenium, mstest, teamcity

I am using this setting to run vstest using mstest in teamcity
Assemblies list : Z:\Test\Tests\bin\Debug\Test.dll /category:"abc Tests"

Getting following error while running vstest using mstest in teamcity

```
Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(String path)
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.Utils.FileUtil.MakeFullPath(String path, String workDir) in c:\Agent\work\2f9f8fe94ae5352e\src\Utils\src\FileUtil.cs:line 40
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.MSTestSupport.Executable.MSTestTargetGenerator.ForEachNewLine(ArrayList argz, String items, String KEY, Boolean fullPath) in c:\Agent\work\2f9f8fe94ae5352e\src\MSTestSupport\src\Executable\MSTestTargetGenerator.cs:line 95
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.MSTestSupport.Executable.MSTestTargetGenerator.GenerateMSTestCommand(IMSTestExeArguments msTestArgs, String resultsFile) in c:\Agent\work\2f9f8fe94ae5352e\src\MSTestSupport\src\Executable\MSTestTargetGenerator.cs:line 61
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.MSTestSupport.Executable.MSTestTargetGenerator.GenerateTargetContent(IMSTestExeArguments mstestArgs) in c:\Agent\work\2f9f8fe94ae5352e\src\MSTestSupport\src\Executable\MSTestTargetGenerator.cs:line 45
   at JetBrains.TeamCity.MSTestSupport.Executable.MSTestExeTestRunnerFactory.CreateRunner(ITestRunArguments args) in c:\Agent\work\2f9f8fe94ae5352e\src\MSTestSupport\src\Executable\MSTestExeTestRunnerFactory.cs:line 29
   at JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.RunnerFactory.FindTestRunner(ITestRunArguments arguments) in c:\Agent\work\2f9f8fe94ae5352e\src\NUnitBootstrap\src\RunnerFactory.cs:line 45
   at JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.RunnerFactory.CreateTestRunner(ITestRunArguments arguments) in c:\Agent\work\2f9f8fe94ae5352e\src\NUnitBootstrap\src\RunnerFactory.cs:line 30
   at JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.NUnitLauncher2.Run2(String[] args) in c:\Agent\work\2f9f8fe94ae5352e\src\NUnitBootstrap\src\NUnitLauncher2.cs:line 88
   at JetBrains.BuildServer.NAntLoggers.NUnitLauncher2.Run(String[] args) in c:\Agent\work\2f9f8fe94ae5352e\src\NUnitBootstrap\src\NUnitLauncher2.cs:line 50
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify your `/category` parametr in **Additional commandline parameters:** field

Comment: "/category:[name of your category.]"

Comment: How to exclude a category ?